# REST API Welcome email best practice

Tags: rest, api-design

I have a REST api with a POST endpoint for user sign up. However, I also want to send a welcome email automatically, but I think it would be bad design to make this as a side effect of the POST request. So far I've come up with three options:

1. Have another endpoint which the browser calls separately to initiate
   the welcome email sending. I don't know what it would be though
   (GET/POST?) and it's somewhat inefficient and prone to abuse since
   the email address has to be sent again.
2. Have an optional
   "sendWelcomeEmail" field in the body of the request.
3. Same as 2, but in the query params.

Maybe this is subjective, but which of the above would be the best practice? I don't feel like any of them fit the bill perfectly, so any other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: It's perfectly acceptable for a `POST` request to have side-effects!

Comment: @Evert Thanks for your input! Which of the three do you think is the best way to do it?

Comment: @akakaba, I clarified this a bit in my answer. Hope this solves it for you

Answer (score 3):

It's fine to have a POST request have side-effects.

I think this would be a good 'best practice'. The assumption here is that you have a "users" resource that represents your list of resources.

Often, `POST` will be used on a 'collection' resource to create a new entry in a collection.

This would then be something like:

```
POST /users
Content-Type: application/json

{
   "firstName": "foo",
   etc...
}
```

It's totally fine for the server to automatically send the welcome email during the same HTTP request. There's no need to create a second endpoint for this.

So my suggestion is to *not* have a secondary HTTP request.